# fadeOut - запустить 2-й раз, пока не погас

Tags: jquery, css3

Накалякал функцию c ajax запросом, при успешном выполнении её появляется скрытый ранее `div` с возвращаемыми из php скрипта данными `data` - появляется шустро, исчезает медленно с эффектом `fadeOut`. Проблема в том, что функцию эту можно запустить со страницы чаще чем успевает скрыться `div` (функция отвечает за включение/выключение объявлений) и при этом он не появляется заного, а продолжает скрываться, если не успел, а после полного скрытия если запустить функцию - отрабатывает заново как надо.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function publishUnpublish(id,proname){
    var input = $('#swith_' + id);
    if(input.is(':checked') == true){
        var status = 0;
        input.checked = false;
    }else{
        var status = 1;
        input.checked = true;
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>index.php?option=com_realty&task=ajax_publishUnpublish',
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        data: {param1:proname,param2:status,param3:id},
        success: function(data){
            $('#message_box').show().text(data).fadeOut(2000);
        }
    })
}
</script>
```

В `div` ничего необычного, он один такой, вот подумал сейчас назначить каждому объявлению такой со своим `id`, но может быть есть другой выход?

```
<div id="message_box"></div>
```

Comment: Посмотрите в эту сторону https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: @xaja работает, спасибо большое! Сделал так: `$('#message_box').stop(true, true).show().text(data).fadeOut(2000);`. Оформите пожалуйста ответ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#message_box').stop(true, true).show().text(data).fadeOut(2000);
```

Документация по [`stop`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)